# Hibernate - Bitronix - Spring - cannot enlist more than one non-XA resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bitronix

I have recently updated to Hibernate `4.2.8.Final` and also tried `4.3.1.Final` however, I have started experiencing the following exception when using a `find` method in a transactional context using the spring framework 3.1 . I am using the Bitronix transaction manager 2.4.3.  I am not sure whether I am using hibernate in the correct manner but as i described, this problem only started after the update of the hibernate version.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4120)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1104)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: error enlisting a JdbcConnectionHandle of a JdbcPooledConnection from datasource defaultDataSource in state ACCESSIBLE with usage count 1 wrapping a JDBC LrcXAConnection on com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@11d1bb73 on a JDBC LrcConnectionHandle on a JDBC LrcXAResource in state NO_TX
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcConnectionHandle.enlistResource(JdbcConnectionHandle.java:87)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(JdbcConnectionHandle.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.BaseProxyHandlerClass.invoke(BaseProxyHandlerClass.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixSystemException: cannot enlist more than one non-XA resource, tried enlisting an XAResourceHolderState with uniqueName=defaultDataSource XAResource=a JDBC LrcXAResource in state NO_TX with XID null, already enlisted: an XAResourceHolderState with uniqueName=defaultDataSource XAResource=a JDBC LrcXAResource in state STARTED (started) with XID a Bitronix XID [737072696E672D62746D0000000023E25108000007C6 : 737072696E672D62746D0000000023E2510F000007CC]
    at bitronix.tm.internal.XAResourceManager.enlist(XAResourceManager.java:107)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.enlistResource(BitronixTransaction.java:130)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.common.TransactionContextHelper.enlistInCurrentTransaction(TransactionContextHelper.java:69)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcConnectionHandle.enlistResource(JdbcConnectionHandle.java:85)
    ... 101 more
```

persistence.xml configuration:

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>default</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>
```

Spring dataSource and bitronix configuration:

```
<bean id="defaultDataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
    depends-on="transactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="className" value="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource" />
    <property name="uniqueName" value="defaultDataSource" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${ds.default.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${ds.default.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${ds.default.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="useTmJoin" value="true" />
    <property name="deferConnectionRelease" value="true" />
    <property name="automaticEnlistingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="true" />
    <property name="isolationLevel" value="READ_COMMITTED" />
    <property name="shareTransactionConnections" value="false"/>
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="driverClassName">${ds.default.driverClass}</prop>
            <prop key="url">${ds.default.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${ds.default.user}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${ds.default.password.encrypted}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bitronixConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
    <property name="logPart1Filename" value="${catalina.base}/logs/tlog/btm1.tlog" />
    <property name="logPart2Filename" value="${catalina.base}/logs/tlog/btm2.tlog" />
    <property name="defaultTransactionTimeout" value="600" />
    <property name="warnAboutZeroResourceTransaction" value="false" />
    <property name="journal" value="null" />
</bean>

<bean id="bitronixTransactionManager" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices"
      factory-method="getTransactionManager" destroy-method="shutdown" depends-on="bitronixConfig" />
```

Comment: It seems your datasources are not configured well: the XA-one is not properly set, so you get this error as JTA can't work with two non-XA sources (it is possible with one only), can you add the spring configuration of your datasources with Bitronix transaction manager?

Comment: I included the spring configuration and persistence.xml being used.

Comment: Make sure also that you use the JDBC drivers that support XA.

Comment: @AndreiI is right: check ds.default.driverClass and see if it is indeed a XA driver.

Comment: As noted in the question - this setup used to work with the older version of hibernate but not with the most recent versions so JDBC drivers should not be the issue here. We are using the MySQL  connector version 5.1.25

Comment: @aseychell Can you print the value of the property ${ds.default.driverClass}? You have to use a driverClass XA-compliant

Comment: ds.default.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: You should use a XA driver; try with com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, however I have a clarification.  The setup that we are currently using is Bitronix with a single NON-TX datasource and no TX sources.  Bitronix allows a single NON-TX datasource and we are using it this way as an optimisation where a single data source is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The provider class changed from `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` in new version of Hibernate check if this is solving your problem.